# powershell regular expression matching other items after quote

Tags: regex, powershell

In this example since its a space it matches it fine. But let's say a regioname doesn't have a space it matches the rest. I just want to match only stuff in the quotes.

`'geoRegionName="Washington" geoCityName="Bonney Lake"' -match '(?<=geoRegionName=)\S+.*?"'`

`$matches = "Bonney Lake"`

This works fine because of space

`'geoRegionName="Washington " geoCityName="Bonney Lake"' -match '(?<=geoRegionName=)\S+.*?"'`

`"Washington "`

But no space and it starts matching other items. Please help me to only match quotes, including cases where name may not be just one word.

`'geoRegionName="Washington" geoCityName="Bonney Lake"' -match '(?<=geoRegionName=)\S+.*?"'`

`"Washington" geoCityName="`

Comment: `'geoRegionName="Washington" geoCityName="Bonney Lake"' -match '(?<=geoRegionName=).+?.*?"'`

Comment: Here's how to match between quotes: `$string -match '(?<=").*?(?=")'`.

Answer (score 1):

Use subexpression `[^"]+` to (greedily) match a nonempty run (`+`) of characters *other* than a `"` (`[^"]`), i.e. everything up to but not including the next `"`, whether or not those characters encompass whitespace:

```
$str = 'geoRegionName="Washington" geoCityName="Bonney Lake"'
if ($str -match '(?<=geoRegionName=")[^"]+') {
  $Matches[0]
}
```

Or, using a [`-replace`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) operation:

```
$str = 'geoRegionName="Washington" geoCityName="Bonney Lake"'
$str -replace '^geoRegionName="([^"]+).+', '$1'
```

Both commands above yield (note that the enclosing `"` were removed, but could easily be included):

```
Washington
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

`\S+` greedily matches a non-empty run (`+`) of *non-whitespace* characters (`\S`), and that *includes `"` chars.*, so `\S+.*?"` kept matching beyond the immediate closing `"` until the next `"` following the first whitespace.